# turtlebot.launch location if Electric is complied from source

Tags: ros, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am just having a problem with localization on the Turtlebot clone I have here.
Firstly, where do I set the calibration parameters if I compile from source on the machine?
In the Tutorials they say to change them in /etc/ros/electric, but am I right in thinking that
that is only visible if I have installed from and sourced the Electric from the debs?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12249/turtlebot.launch-location-if-electric-is-complied-from-source/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want the files in /etc configure upstart

**Configure Upstart**

It is recommended to use Upstart to start your robot:

```
roscd turtlebot_bringup/upstart
sudo ./install.bash wlan0
```

You should replace wlan0 with the name of your wifi interface.

For Ubuntu 11.10 , install daemontools which is need by turtlebot_start.

```
sudo apt-get install daemontools
```

**Setup NTP**

Clock synchronization is important for ROS. Chrony has been found to be the best ntp client over lossy wireless.

manually sync NTP

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Install Chrony

```
sudo apt-get install chrony
```

These are the last half of the instructions here: http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Install

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2012-02-07**:
Hi Melonee, thank you. However, I did manage to get upstart installed it wasn't running as expected. So, say I reboot the Turtlebot, then tried to run teleop, there would be no movement. So, I reverted back to minimal.launch. I've a Turtlebot Clone not installed from an image.